# OpenCV process all text to be black on white (segmentation)

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

Is it possible to somehow make it so that all text in a document is black on white after thresholding. I've been looking online alot but I haven't been able to come to a solution. My current thresholded image is: https://i.ibb.co/Rpqcp7v/thresh.jpg

The document needs to be read by an OCR and for that I need to have the areas that are currently white on black, to be inverted. How would I go about doing this? my current code:

```
# thresholding
def thresholding(image):
    # thresholds the image into a binary image (black and white)
    return cv2.threshold(image, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Comment: Why wouldn't regular OCR work with your current thresholding? The images shouldn't get detected and therefor shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: I've just noticed that very often the wrong data is being read out. so I have several ways of preprocessing, it picks the highest confidence result in the end and usually the result is a lot better this way. This is just still the main obstacle I have.

Comment: Maybe try this to get just the text from the image, then run you're OCR on it after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54125216/9178557

Comment: Already tried Inverted thresholding, but it wouldnt fix the problem right? Unless i could combine the resulting images somehow (take the white background area from each image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a median filter to estimate the dominant color (background).

Then subtract the image from that... you'll get white text on black background. I'm using the *absolute* difference. Invert for black on white.

```py
im = cv.imread("thresh.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im = cv.pyrDown(cv.pyrDown(im)) # picture too large for stack overflow
bg = cv.medianBlur(im, 51) # suitably large kernel to cover all text
out = 255 - cv.absdiff(bg, im)
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is fantastic and works great. I do get a slightly different result https://i.ibb.co/C8Gg9y1/thresh-0.jpg . the main problem here is for example the name on top, it is unreadable by the OCR. which is odd since I basically copied your solution. why do I get a different result .-.

Comment: I didn't reveal all in my solution. I downscaled the input a few times. use a larger kernel size to compensate. it's a fiddle factor.

Comment: I see. it works better when I put it on 75 for example. Thank you!

Comment: That's the best image processing method I'have ever seen for an ocr operation. Thank you.